# Need Help with Differentiation

Tags: derivatives

I came across below expression where I needed to find the value of K where the maximum value will occur for the below function

$P=\binom{k}{2} \times 2^{n-k}$

I re-wrote it as

$P=2^{n-1} \times \{\frac{k^2-k}{2^k}\}$

differentiating it with respect to k

$\frac{dP}{dk}=2^{n-1}  \times \Biggl( \frac{(2k-1)-(k^2-k)(log2^k)}{2^k} \Biggr)$

My query is, can I keep base of log in the above expression to 2?

I know I need to equate the above value to 0, to find the critical point.

Please help me further I am stuck here.

Comment: The derivative of $2^k$ is $2^k\log 2$.

Comment: Yeah in the above shown step I have removed $2^k$ from both numerator and denominator.

Comment: Why not take logs and use $$\log(m!) = \sum_{j=1}^{m} \log(j)$$ It should make life easier.

Comment: You will get $\log2$, not $\log2^k$, in the numerator. On equating to $0$, you will get a quadratic in $k$, which can be solved easily, though integral solutions are not guaranteed